# React native android TouchableNativeFeedback flashes black on press

Tags: android, react-native

When I press and hold TouchableNativeFeedback its background flashes black. I have background prop set to `TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackgroundBorderless()` on it. Changing it to `TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground()` or `TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('red', false)` doesn't change anything. Maybe I miss some configureation? What could cause such an effect? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the example on React Native's [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback.html) and it seems to be working normally on my Android emulator (Genymotion). Here's the code:

```
renderButton: function() {
  return (
    <TouchableNativeFeedback
        onPress={this._onPressButton}
        background={TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground()}>
      <View style={{width: 150, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <Text style={{margin: 30}}>Button</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
  );
}
```